# How do I count the number of specific characters in a string in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs

Let's say I have a string s.

And this string s could contain this:

```
asdf-asdfasdfasf-fasdf-asdfasdfasdf
```

or this:

```
asf-asdfaf
```

but also this:

```
aasdaf
```

How do I count the number of dashes (-) in this string using Emacs Lisp and store this number in some variable e.g. count-of-dashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function should do it:

```el
(defun count-chars (char str)
  (let ((s (char-to-string char))
        (count 0)
        (start-pos -1))
    (while (setq start-pos (string-search s str (+ 1 start-pos)))
      (setq count (+ 1 count)))
    count))
```

You call it like this:

```el
(count-chars ?- "---") ==> 3
(count-chars ?- "foo-bar") ==> 1
(count-chars ?- "-foo-bar-baz") ==> 3
(count-chars ?- "foobarbaz") ==> 0
```

To set a variable to the number found, you just use
`setq`:

```el
(setq count-of-chars (count-chars ?- "foo-bar-baz"))
```

Basically, we loop looking for the first dash: if we find it we remember where so that we start looking at the place just to the right of it the next time around the loop. The loop body then just counts every one we see. When we can't find any more, `string-search` (and the `setq`) returns `nil` and the loop exits, whereupon we return the accumulated `count`. See the doc string of the function `string-search` with `C-h f string-search` for the details.

Another method is more akin to the `split` string method of python: `split-string` splits a string on a separator into a list of parts. We then count the parts (the length of the list) and subtract 1: `"a-b-c"` is split into `("a" "b" "c")` so there are three parts but only two separators.

```el
(defun count-chars (char str)
  (let ((s (char-to-string char)))
    (- (length (split-string str s)) 1)))
```

Again, see the doc string of `split-string` (`C-h f split-string`) for all the details.

In both cases, we converted the character argument to a string argument, because both `string-search` in the first case and `split-string` in the second expect a string argument (to search for in the first case and to use as a separator in the second case - in fact, `split-string` can use a regular expression as a separator). Characters and strings are different data types in Emacs Lisp, so the conversion is necessary *if* you really want a character s the first argument of `count-chars`. But you could make it a string instead:

```el
(defun count-seps (sep str)
   (- (length (split-string str sep)) 1))
```

and then you would call it like this instead:

```el
(count-seps "-" "abc-def-ghi-")
```

which is simpler *and* more general:

```el
(count-seps "-;-" "abc-;-def") ==> 1
```

but you do have to worry about special characters in the separator string:

```le
(count-seps "-*-" "abcd-------def") ==> 1
```

since the regular expression `-*-` matches *one or more dashes* so it matches all seven dashes: there is only one separator. Whether that's what you want is debatable. If you don't want it, you'd need to escape the special characters in the separator string:

```el
(defun count-chars (sep str)
   (let ((qsep (regexp-quote sep)))
     (- (length (split-string str qsep)) 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks, was it a deliberate decision to not include such a common function as the count function in Emacs Lisp? Clojure, for example, has it.

Comment: Emacs Lisp is an extension language for Emacs, not a general purpose programming language (in contrast to Clojure). There are many functions that are not included in it. It tends to favor buffer-based functions because those are used most frequently in extensions and it skimps on string functions which are less useful for that purpose. But there are third-party libraries (e.g. [s.el](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) and [dash.el](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) and many others) that fill in some of the perceived holes.

Comment: As said above, there *is* such a function, in some sense: `count-matches`. The thing is that it operates on a buffer, and not on strings (for reason explained by the previous comment). A usual workaround is to wrap this in a call to
`(with-temp-buffer
  (insert <the string>)
  <use buffer-related functions>
  (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))))`

Comment: Yes, that is a useful and frequently used idiom in Emacs Lisp. It is also pretty efficient: Emacs Lisp deals with buffers all the time, so the buffer functions have been optimized in various ways.

Comment: @Numbra: I think you mentioned `count-matches` in a different question, not this one. Be that as it may, you might want to add the buffer-idiom solution as an answer here. I think it would be useful.